# Create a range from multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a range from multiple cells. Something like this:

I would like to have the following 4 cells:

- `Cells(4, 7)`
- `Cells(4, 8)`
- `Cells(8, 7)`
- `Cells(8, 8)`

to be extracted from a file and then saved to another file as its first row.

I wrote something like this:

```
With mybook.Worksheets(5)
    Set sourceRange = .Range(Cells(4, 7), Cells(4, 8), 
                             Cells(8, 7), Cells(8, 8))
End With
```

The problem I face is that only the `Cells (4,7)` and `Cells (4,8)` appear in the summary sheet.

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very rudimentary approach.

```
Sub Transfer4Cells()
    Dim sSht As Worksheet, tSht As Worksheet
    Dim sRng As Range, tRng As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set sSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change as needed.
    Set tSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Change as needed.
    Set sRng = sSht.Range("G4,H4,G8,H8") 'You can add more cells here.
    Pos = 1
    For Each Rng In sRng
        tSht.Cells(1, Pos).Value = Rng.Value
        Pos = Pos + 1
    Next Rng
End Sub
```

While not the perfect solution, the approach is very flexible if you only need it to extract only those 4 cells, or maybe even more.

Hope this helps.